# Integrating Mopub ads into Cocos2dx 2.1

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, mopub

The Mopub integration instructions suggest creating the ad view in xml with a snippet like this:

```
<com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/adview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
/>
```

Then the instructions suggest creating the ad view in the activity's create method like this:

```
moPubView = (MoPubView)findViewById(R.id.adview);
moPubView.setAdUnitId("123412341234");
moPubView.loadAd();
```

Unfortunately `moPubView` is not created because Cocos2dx 2.1 doesn't use XML for layout anymore. So the app crashes on launch due to a null pointer exception.

I tried passing `R.layout.main` to `setContentView` before attempting to create the ad view. This does successfully create the ad view however the rest of the app isn't visible.

**How can I create a view like the one above programmatically without using XML?**

I think this solve the null pointer exception issue without having to call `setContentView`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private static BannerAdManager m_adDelegate = null;
private static FrameLayout.LayoutParams m_bannerParam = null;
private static FrameLayout m_appLayout = null;


public static void initialize(Activity p_activity)
{
    // create instance of delegate
    if( m_adDelegate == null )
    {
        m_adDelegate = new BannerAdManager();
    }

    m_activity = p_activity;


    //~~~setup mopub banner ad
    //~~~create mopub ad view
    m_mopubView = new MoPubView(m_activity);

    m_bannerParam = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(   
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    );

    m_mopubView.setAdUnitId(Config_Android._ID);
    m_mopubView.setBannerAdListener(m_adDelegate);
    m_mopubView.loadAd();

    //get current layout
    m_appLayout = (FrameLayout) m_activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    // set default alignment
    m_bannerParam.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER;

    //add mopub view to layout
    m_appLayout.addView(m_mopubView, m_bannerParam);

}

    public static void setBannerPositionTopWithPadding(float p_padding)
    {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run()
            {
                activity = getActivity();

                m_bannerParam.gravity  = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER;
                m_bannerParam.width    = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                m_bannerParam.height   = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

                m_bannerParam.topMargin = (int) p_padding;

                m_appLayout.updateViewLayout(m_mopubView, m_bannerParam);
                m_mopubView.refreshDrawableState();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: excuse me :) I am a relatively newbie in Android and I didn't understand a single thing in the above code..Could anyone please explain what ChaCha meant? I'm trying to do the same in a small app.

Comment: In the latest MoPub SDK, there is nothing like BannerAdManager! or am I mising something?