# How can I create a view and set attributes in Android through Code?

Tags: android, libgdx, mopub

Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am integrating MoPub SDK into my libGDX game and in MoPub documentation they are saying to create the MopubView in layout.xml like shown above.  And then, do the following:

```
moPubView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adview);
moPubView.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxxxxxx"); // Enter your Ad Unit ID from www.mopub.com
moPubView.loadAd();
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

// Create the libgdx View
View gameView = initializeForView(new TBGame(this), config);

// Add the libgdx view
layout.addView(gameView);
layout.addView(moPubView)

setContentView(layout);
```

But libGDX won't load my xml file as it doesn't need it, resulting in null pointer exception whenever the execution reaches the above line. So the solution seems to be creating the view from code? How can I do that? A very similar question is here  [Integrating Mopub ads into Cocos2dx 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664972/integrating-mopub-ads-into-cocos2dx-2-1/18267730) but the solution stated there is NOT valid for the latest MoPub SDK.

Edit: This is the MoPubView class https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/blob/master/mopub-sdk/src/main/java/com/mopub/mobileads/MoPubView.java

Attachment: Part of stack trace attached here:
[image: Stacktrace]

Comment: Please post your MoPubView class, than even we can say anything, or the full exception stack.

Comment: I've updated the post with the link to MoPubView class. please check it. I will post the stack trace soon.

Comment: there is a slight change in the stack trace. please check now as this is the one with the original code

Answer (score 0):

if your call to findViewById is in an activity, you need to call setContentView with layout in onCreate :
setContentView(R.layout.layout);
(btw, try a more descriptive name)

otherwise - to load dynamically look there : [How to load layout in code from xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063409/how-to-load-layout-in-code-from-xml-file) and just use the resulting view as you wish, probably something like view.findViewById

Comment: yes. i am doing that but the problem is precisely with this line moPubView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adview); layout xml is not loaded by the game engine I am using

Comment: there is a slight change in the stack trace. please check now as this is the one with the original code

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this :

```
    setContentView(relativeLayout);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    relativeLayout.addView(yourchildView);
```

Comment: yes, i am doing that. please see the code again. i've updated it

Comment: change this line moPubView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adview); with moPubView = new MoPubView(); and give position will code dont take from xml id

Comment: there is a slight change in the stack trace. please check now as this is the one with the original code.